# Sort column with text and number

Tags: sorting, text, numbers

I am trying to sort several csv files by the first column. Here is a an example of the output that I get:

```
OR7
OR8
OR10
OR100
OR101
OR102
OR103
OR104
OR105
OR106
OR107
OR109
OR11
OR111
OR113
OR114
OR115
OR117
OR119
```

Here is the command that I am using: `sort -k 1.3,1.4n -k1.5n file` (I am sorting by the first column)
However I would like to have it sorted like this:

```
OR7
OR8
OR10
OR11
OR100
OR101
OR102
OR103
OR104
OR105
OR106
OR107
OR109
OR111
OR113
OR114
OR115
OR117
OR119
```

I know that there are other similar questions here, but I could not figure out how to adapt their solution to my problem. 
I am also using MacOS. I was just looking at an Ubuntu machine and the sort has more option (checking "man sort"). For example, when I try to use -V on my computer it does not work.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a way around it in R. Since my goal was to make a Trellis plot. What I did was to set the column with the gene names as a factor and in the order I wanted. For example:

```
OR$Gene<-factor(OR$Gene, levels=(c("OR2", "OR3", "OR4", "OR5", "OR6", "OR7", "OR8", "OR10", "OR11", "OR12", "OR13", "OR14", "OR15", "OR16", "OR17", "OR18", "OR19", "OR20", "OR21", "OR23", "OR24", "OR25", "OR26", "OR27", "OR28", "OR30", "OR31", "OR33", "OR36", "OR39", "OR41", "OR42", "OR43", "OR44", "OR45", "OR47", "OR48", "OR49", "OR50", "OR52", "OR55", "OR56", "OR59", "OR62", "OR63", "OR66", "OR67", "OR69", "OR70", "OR71", "OR72", "OR76", "OR78", "OR79", "OR80", "OR81", "OR84", "OR85", "OR86", "OR87", "OR88", "OR91", "OR92", "OR93", "OR94", "OR95", "OR96", "OR97", "OR98", "OR100", "OR101", "OR102", "OR103", "OR104", "OR105", "OR106", "OR107", "OR109", "OR111", "OR113", "OR114", "OR115", "OR117", "OR119", "OR121", "OR122", "OR123", "OR124", "OR125", "OR126", "OR130"))
```

Then with the xyplot print command I used the index.cond:

```
index.cond = list(OR$Gene),
```

Well I got what I wanted, I am sure might be an easier way out there.
Best,